# What does map(-2:2, rnorm, n = 5) do? Why? What does map_dbl(-2:2, rnorm, n = 5) do? Why?

Tags: r

This is a problem in R for data science by Hadley. 
The results for map(-2:2, rnorm, n = 5)  is a list of 5 double vector.
and  map_dbl(-2:2, rnorm, n = 5) is a error says "Error: Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector". 
But I don't know why.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map(-2:2, rnorm, n = 5)` is the list of vectors `rnorm(-2, n=5)`, `rnorm(-1, n=5)`, `rnorm(0, n=5)`, `rnorm(1, n=5)`, `rnorm(2, n=5)`.

Since these vectors have not length 1, `map_dbl(-2:2, rnorm, n = 5)` throws an error. For example `map_dbl(-2:2, rnorm, n = 1)` does not return an error, it is the vector made of `rnorm(-2, n=1)`, `rnorm(-1, n=1)`, `rnorm(0, n=1)`, `rnorm(1, n=1)`, `rnorm(2, n=1)`.